# Regex not matching in sed

Tags: regex, sed, pattern-matching, match

I have used regexs for years, and never come across this problem. On example websites (like http://regexone.com/lesson/1) where I can play around with what I'm trying to do, it matches, but in the unix shell using `sed`, it doesn't match. I discovered this when trying to write logcheck skipping rules.

```
$ echo 'Hello, world!' | sed '/^\w\w\wlo, wor.*$/d'
$
```

Works, but

```
$ echo 'Hello, world!' | sed '/^\w{3}lo, wor.*$/d'
Hello, world!
```

doesn't. It doesn't see 3 alphanums with the {3} it seems.

I found this out by trying to do reductions on

```
$ echo "Jul 15 11:31:08 gateway-laptop dbus[3076]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'"|sed "/^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ dbus\[[0-9]+\]: \[system\].*/d"
Jul 15 11:31:08 gateway-laptop dbus[3076]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
```

Which I would have thought should match. Reducing this complexity, this doesn't match

```
$ echo "Jul 15 11:31:08 gateway-laptop dbus[3076]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'"|sed "/^\w{3}.*"/d
Jul 15 11:31:08 gateway-laptop dbus[3076]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
```

It looks like its behavior ^\w{3} should match the first 3 alphanumeric characters in the line, then the .* should match the rest of the line to the EOL.

Comment: Updated the tags; `bash` has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the braces otherwise sed's default behavior is to match `{} or ()` literally:

```
echo 'Hello, world!' | gsed '/^\w\{3\}lo, wor.*$/d'
```

Or else you need `-r` flag for extended regex capabilities:

```
echo 'Hello, world!' | gsed -r '/^\w{3}lo, wor.*$/d'
```

Comment: Ah. Great catch. I didn't think about this because I think logcheck uses sed, but doesn't use the escape. Here is an example from a working rule that came with logcheck: ^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ acpid: action exited with status 0$

I am puzzeled why the above doesn't work in logcheck, but I'll try it using the logcheck-test tool. This answers the above question, though, so I will mark it as answered. Thank you.